# Recommended web development plugins for NetBeans

Tags: plugins, netbeans

I was wondering if anyone has a preferred set of plugins that they use for NetBeans. Specifically for general web development projects using: xHTML, CSS, PHP, MySQL, JavaScript and jQuery.

I am just getting started with the IDE and have been using some plugins that are available through the program interface.

Comment: Aptana Suite might be exactly what you are looking for: http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2 EDIT: Note, Aptana is built on Eclipse. I like Eclipse more than NetBeans, so it's a matter of opinion I suppose.

Comment: I agree, I tried Aptana. I am using Ubuntu and after 2 days the program stopped loading. So, rather than troubleshoot it, I resorted to netBeans. But, if netBeans is not preferred for web development, I may go back to Aptana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried both Aptana Studio (either standalone or Eclipse plugin version) and Netbeans. For MY personal taste and needs, I've choosen Netbeans as my main IDE.

I think there's no "THE" IDE, the perfect one. Both are very good IDEs, among many others.
Try both Aptana and Netbeans, so you'll realize which one is the best for YOUR needs!

By the way, one plugin I can't live without is Zen Coding (for Netbeans, Eclipse/Aptana + others): http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

Comment: "THE IDE" for PHP is no PHPStorm, it is like combination of netbeans and Sublime text, clen fast and huge amount of functions and tools. It is paid though.

Comment: Just an update: Nowadays I use Sublime Text + Emmet Plugin. :)

Answer (score 3):

I use two Netbeans plugins

- [prefixr](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39949/prefixr) to auto prefix my css3 transition / animation / ..
- [Emmet](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48315/emmet) to improves HTML & CSS workflow

## 1° Prefixr

- default **shortcut** on mac : `^+⌘+P` (`ctrl + cmd + P`)
- **download** link : http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39949/prefixr
- **screenshot** :
- [image: before & after prefixr]

---

## 2° Emmet (new zen coding)

- default **shortcut** to expand (on mac) : `^+⌘+N` (`ctrl + cmd + N`)
- **download** link : [enter link description here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48315/emmet)
- **installation guide** : https://github.com/emmetio/netbeans
- Emmet **official** website : http://emmet.io/
- Emmet **cheat sheet** : http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/
- **screenshot** :
- [image: emmet expand example]

---

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

For the Netbeans IDE I'm always using two extra plugins:

- ["Zen-Coding" plugin](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/): This plugin allows you to expand expressions—similar to CSS selectors—into HTML code, which is very helpful and helps you typing your code a lot faster.
- ["Annoyance Whacker" plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/17962/annoyance-whacker): This plugin moves the status bar of the Netbeans IDE to the top of the screen next to the menu bar. So now you have more vertical space on your screen.

It would be great to see more recommendations on useful Netbeans plugins from other people on stackoverflow!